# Getting installed fonts from client Machine

Tags: java

Could anyone point me about how to get installed fonts from client machine?

I have tried Java Webservice to retrieve fronts but after deploying it returns me server's installed fonts but I wan't fonts from client machine.

```
GraphicsEnvironment e = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Font[] fonts = e.getAllFonts(); // Get the fonts
for (Font f : fonts) {
    System.out.println(f.getFontName());
}
```

Comment: Side note: `// Get the fonts` is a very redundant comment as the method's name is `getAllFonts`. Don't get used to comment everything.

Comment: Is client just invoking webservice? Then in that case you won't get list of fonts. If its Java application running on client machine, then yes you can get the list.

Comment: That is not possible. You will need to either use JavaScript or an applet.

Answer (score 1):

For information about the client, your code must be running on the client. The web service is executed on the server, so you get the server information. If you do not have the ability to run Java code on the client, then you need to look for a solution JavaScript + AJAX